# Where can I get digital cartographic maps of Brazil?

Tags: brazil, geospatial, data-request

I have a personal database of cartographic maps that I used for many purposes, mostly planning campings and other outside adventures.

I'd like to have similar data about Brazil.

Comment: @Vince digital is key word here, because cartographic maps are usually sold printed

Comment: yeah, I was more wondering about the site's scope, which is mostly about machine-readable data and therefore digital. But maps are not machine-readable and some open data can be printed.

Comment: You might be able to find data at ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/, but IBGE's FTP is a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Street Maps and GEOTIFF Files from MODIS, wold do the job.

Comment: how can I get GEOTIFFs from MODIS?

Comment: http://earthdata.nasa.gov/lance

Answer (score 3):

As other have already mentioned, [Open Street Maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/-9.75/-53.31) is your friend. The covered details depends largely on the number people that have visited the region and actually added data to OSM. You can get an idea of how much detail in  a region is covered at the [Garmin osm site](http://garmin.openstreetmap.nl/). The size of each tile more or less reflects the size of the resulting image file. The more details, smaller the tile. This is a very rough estimate though. It does not mean that the bigger the tile the lesser the quality. Some brazilian regions (e.g. The amazon), do not contain that much infrastructure to cover.